# Generate postgresql primary key as "AS IDENTITY" instead of serial4 using jpa @Id annotation

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I have the following class:

```java
// ... Imports, etc.

public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private String description;

// ... More stuff below
```

I was expecting it to generate the primary key using `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`, as the following DDL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.items (
    id int4  NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY( INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 START 1 CACHE 1 NO CYCLE),
    title varchar(255) NULL,
    description varchar(255) NULL
    CONSTRAINT items_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

But instead, the pk was generated using `serial4`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.items (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    title varchar(255) NULL,
    description varchar(255) NULL
    CONSTRAINT items_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT items_user_id_key UNIQUE (user_id),
);
```

I tried using `@Column` on the `id` field to change how the value is generated:

```java
// ... Imports, etc.

public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY")
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private String description;

// ... More stuff below
```

And I also tried changing the strategy to `GenerationType.AUTO`, but the primary key is still being generated as `serial4`.

Is there a way to force jpa to generate the primary key using `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` on postgresql?

Comment: Key generation choices are implementation specific, and DDL generation is a one time operation - why not just use it to get the scripts and modify them as you want?

Comment: Hi @Chris, sorry being late. The reason why I'm confused by the behavior is that I was expecting it to actually change the table's generation schema, but it does not do anything, it just gets ignored completely. I'm aware that I can modify them as I want, but that would only solve the problem, not my lack of understanding of why this happens

Comment: Such mechanisms are internal to the JPA provider - there is nothing general to JPA other than to override the column the definition as you've tried, and even then it is up to the provider on how to handle that with any of the other settings. DDL is more an add on or after thought for JPA - useful to get things started, but not meant for production/enterprise systems.